# advertisingIdentifier crash - failed to resume in time

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm getting these crash reports on itunes connect.
It seems that it's related to advertisingIdentifier in some way, which is called on 2 different threads.

Did you encounter something like this? Can you tell what causes it?

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
xxxx failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 7.840 (user 7.840, system 0.000), 42% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.001, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b906eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b907048 mach_msg + 36
2   MobileCoreServices              0x34a2d824 _LSPluginClient_GetAdvertisingIdentifier + 48
3   MobileCoreServices              0x34a319b4 _LSCopyAdvertisingIdentifier + 36
4   MobileCoreServices              0x34a19320 __56-[LSApplicationWorkspace deviceIdentifierForAdvertising]_block_invoke_0 + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b8304b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b8363f2 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 38
7   MobileCoreServices              0x34a192a6 -[LSApplicationWorkspace deviceIdentifierForAdvertising] + 34
8   AdSupport                       0x32e52db2 -[ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier] + 54
9   xxxx                    0x001f0f9e +[CBIdentity cbuia] + 62
10  xxxx                    0x001f121a +[CBIdentity combinedIdentifier] + 134
11  xxxx                    0x001f0e38 +[CBIdentity hexIdentifier] + 28
12  xxxx                    0x001ecade -[CBAPIRequest appendDeviceInfoParams] + 418
13  xxxx                    0x001e908a -[Chartboost startSession] + 254
14  xxxx                    0x0014eda2 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.mm:317)

...

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b906f04 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b8362fc _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$mp + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b83644a dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 126
3   MobileCoreServices              0x34a192a6 -[LSApplicationWorkspace deviceIdentifierForAdvertising] + 34
4   AdSupport                       0x32e52db2 -[ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier] + 54
5   xxxx                    0x0026bed6 +[FlurryUtil getIdentifierForAdvertiser] + 66
6   xxxx                    0x002687b2 -[FlurrySession dataForSessions:] + 786
7   xxxx                    0x002677c8 -[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerIncludingCurrentSession:] + 512
8   xxxx                    0x002675c2 -[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerForCreateSession] + 18
9   xxxx                    0x00273a82 __50-[FlurryImpl sendSessionsToServerForCreateSession]_block_invoke_0 + 34
```

Answer (score 1):

The advertising ID is read from an encrypted file so if the user had reboot and had not unlocked their phone with the pin then accessing the identifier would return null and if that app isn't prepared to handle that it might crash.

Comment: Do you have any reference that the ad ID is encrypted? I can see in the docs for the deprecated `identifierForVendor` that it says that, but there the UUID is optional. The UUID is not optional for `advertisingIdentifier`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's background task related, in your case something about both ChartBoost and Flurry doing background tasks.

I was seeing the same effect when doing a background network call on app suspend, when an analytics framework and something else were also I think doing some background work...

In my case I made sure the network calls I were doing were completed in under ten seconds at which point I killed the background task, or if it finished earlier I also killed the background task.  I also terminated the background task when the app was about to resume.

If all you have going a far as background tasks is whatever work the libraries are doing, then  try removing one and see if you have the same issue.  Worst case is that possibly you could figure out how to stop one of the libraries from doing background processing (I think Flurry at least has an option where you can tell it not to send data in the background) and see if that helps also.